# Cannot find name TS2304 when trying to read HTML elements

Tags: html, typescript

I've got an IDE at work with VS Code and the Easy Compile extension (can't just install NPM etc.)

I'm trying to just read two text areas so I can process them for the output, but for right I'm just going to put them on the page.

I've manually adjusted the .js and it works just fine, it's just the .ts file that's not happy.

In the .ts

```
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    output.innerHTML = nameInput.value + "are doing " + roleInput.value
}
```

in HTML

```
<form id="userForm">
        <div id="people">
            <label for="nameInput">Enter names, separated by commas</label>
            <textarea id="nameInput" name="namelist" required></textarea>
        </div>
     <div id="roles">
          <label for="roleInput">Enter locations to inspect, separated by commas.</label>
         <textarea id="roleInput" name="rolelist" required></textarea>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" type="Submit">Generate your list!</button>
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
```

I'm expecting the page to put the text on in the 'output' div.

but

TS is giving me

Cannot find name 'output'.

Cannot find name 'nameInput'.

Cannot find name 'roleInput'.

ts(2304) errors.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't like globals, like those created by the browser for elements with IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your commen below, it looks like you're not using *global* objects as I initially thought, you're just using objects from the parent context.

```js
const output: HTMLTextAreaElement = document.getElementById(...)
```

won't work - `getElementById` returns an `HTMLElement`. Unfortunately, `getElementById` isn't generic. If you were using `querySelector`, you could do

```js
const output = document.querySelector<HTMLTextAreaElement>(...)
```

which tells TS that you're expecting the return to be a TextArea element. Instead, you have to type assert

```js
const output = document.getElementById(...) as HTMLTextAreaElement
```

Now output has the correct type.

---

**old response**

As mentioned in a comment, TS doesn't play nicely out of the box with globals.

If you know what your `global` is going to look like, you can use ambient types / type augmentation to type globals.

In your above example, you can give your globals ambient types:

```
declare var output: ...
declare var nameInput: ...
declare var roleInput: ...
```

This can be placed either in the file you reference them in, or in a types file (specified via `types` or `typeRoots` in your `tsconfig.json`).

A "better" (more idiomatic) way to specify these types if via type augmentation of the global object.

for a browser based app, it would look like

```
declare interface Window {
  output: ...
  nameInput: ...
  roleInput: ...
}
```

and for node it would look like

```
declare var global {
  ...
}
```

**note**: you must prefix your globals with `window.` or `global.` for type augmentation to work.

Comment: Since those three elements are the entirety of what I needed, I just declared them like `const output: any = document.getElementById("output")` and it's all copacetic now.

I was't sure which type to set nameInput and roleInput to. HTMLTextAreaElement tossed a lot of errors (missing properties). 

It works now though, and I am learning more about what I'm doing. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the update! I've made adjustments and it didn't break anything. {:0)